# sshpass does not work at HPUX 11.31

Tags: ssh, sshpass

Does anyone successfully run sshpass at HPUX 11.31 ?

I’ve compiled sshpass 1.06 at HPUX 1131, but when I run it, I got errors.
The command I run :

```
sshpass -p Abcd1234 ssh -vvv nledfd02 date
```

I am able to connect by entering a password. Thus, the command `ssh -vvv nledfd02 date` works fine.

The error message in the console output :

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 50 padlen 14 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive

Permission denied, please try again.

debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address

debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 50 padlen 14 extra_pad 64)

debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply

Received disconnect from 10.8.65.51: 2: Too many authentication failures for test1
```

The error message in sshd output :

```
root@NLEDFD02   [/tmp/sshpass/sshpass105]

# /opt/ssh/sbin/sshd -d


Postponed keyboard-interactive for test1 from 10.8.65.51 port 52444 ssh2 [preauth]

PAM: Authentication failed for test1 from 10.8.65.51

Failed keyboard-interactive/pam for test1 from 10.8.65.51 port 52444 ssh2

debug1: Entering record_failed_login uid 0 

debug1: audit event euid 0 user test1 event 5 (AUTH_FAIL_KBDINT)

debug1: aud_sav_flag=1

debug1: userauth-request for user test1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]

debug1: attempt 4 failures 3 [preauth]

Failed none for test1 from 10.8.65.51 port 52444 ssh2

debug1: audit event euid 0 user test1 event 3 (AUTH_FAIL_NONE)

debug1: userauth-request for user test1 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]

debug1: attempt 5 failures 4 [preauth]

Failed password for test1 from 10.8.65.51 port 52444 ssh2

debug1: Entering record_failed_login uid 0 

debug1: audit event euid 0 user test1 event 4 (AUTH_FAIL_PASSWD)

debug1: aud_sav_flag=1

Disconnecting: Too many authentication failures for test1 [preauth]

debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]

debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed

debug1: audit event euid 0 user test1 event 0 (LOGIN_EXCEED_MAXTRIES)

debug1: aud_sav_flag=1

debug1: do_cleanup

debug1: PAM: cleanup

debug1: Killing privsep child 21704

debug1: audit event euid 0 user test1 event 12 (CONNECTION_ABANDON)

debug1: aud_sav_flag=1

root@NLEDFD02   [/tmp/sshpass/sshpass105]
# uname -a
HP-UX NLEDFD02 B.11.31 U ia64 3687447314 unlimited-user license

root@NLEDFD02   [/tmp/sshpass/sshpass105]
# cc -V
(Bundled) cc: HP C/aC++ B3910B A.06.12 [Oct 11 2006]

root@NLEDFD02   [/tmp/sshpass/sshpass105]
# ssh -version
OpenSSH_6.2p1+sftpfilecontrol-v1.3-hpn13v12, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
HP-UX Secure Shell-A.06.20.006, HP-UX Secure Shell version
```

Comment: `sshpass` by design is hacking. u can try [passh](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh) though i'm not sure if it compiles on hp-ux.

Comment: Posted the underlying question to SO. Maybe someone here knows the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034206/how-to-get-hpux-to-adopt-a-tty-as-controlling

Comment: @whjm, would love to hear why you think sshpass is a hack by design.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - take a look at the example here: https://github.com/clarkwang/passh (under **why i wrote passh**)

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - utils like Expect, pexpect, Expect.pm... are not following the sshpass way when dealing with PTYs.

Comment: but as the [example #1](https://github.com/clarkwang/passh) says, *sshpass is better in its own way*.